# Hide column while exporting to excel from html table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I have a html table which I have to export to excel , but while doing so, I dont want some of the td elements to be exported. When I apply javascript to hide the td, the changes are being applied only to the view form and not to the the content being exported.

Need help in how to export in this case.

I have included html, css and script all in one page.

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="myDiv">
<table id="metrics" border="1px" cellspacing="0 px" style="border-style:  solid; border-color: Black;
        border-width: thin;">
        <tr>
            <td style= "background-color: #bfbfbf;  font-size: small; color: black;">
                LOB
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class="hillbillyForm" data-displayname='LOB' style="display:none;"></span>

           </td>
       </tr>
</table>
    <input type="button" id="btnExport"  value="Export" onclick="TableToExcel('metrics');" />
</div>
</body>
```

Here I want to hide the td which contains span class "hillbillyForm"

The javascript That I am using is

```
    function TableToExcel(tableid) {

        var id = $('[id$="' + tableid + '"]');
        var $clonedTable = $("id").clone();
        $clonedTable.find('[style = "display: none"]').remove();
        var strCopy = $('<div></div>').html(id.clone()).html();

        window.clipboardData.setData("Text", strCopy);

        var objExcel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");

        objExcel.visible = false; var objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add; var objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1); objWorksheet.Paste; objExcel.visible = true;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So what I'm understanding is that you want to remove all TD's which have a direct child with the class hillbillyForm.

You can do something like this:

```
var form = document.getElementById(tableid),
    exportForm = form.cloneNode(true),
    elementsToRemove = exportForm.querySelectorAll('.hillbillyForm');

for (var i = elementsToRemove.length; i--;){
    var td = elementsToRemove[i].parentElement;
    if (td) td.parentElement.removeChild(td);
}
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A1rPun/xc2sfyft/)

Comment: still the columns are visible in excel